# Prove/disprove that we cannot have $V = U_1 \oplus U_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inverse

$V$ vector space of upper triangular $3\times3$ matrices.

$1$ and $2$ are subspaces of $$.

Every non-zero member of $1$ is invertible. Every member of $2$ is non-invertible.

> Prove/disprove that we cannot have $=1⊕2$

I think that this is correct and

My idea is to prove that  $U1 \cap U2 \ne {\{0}\}$

But I"m having hard time to write General member for $U1$ and $U2$

any hint how to prove this ?

thanks

Comment: $U_1\cap U_2$ is $0$, pretty much by definition

Comment: Hint: If $V = U_1 \oplus U_2$, then every element of $V$ would be uniquely written as a sum $u_1 + u_2$ for $u_1 \in U_1, u_2 \in U_2$.

Comment: Another hint: Try to write down a possible candidate for the subspace $U_1$. In particular, try to write down some basis.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong If the operation were addition, $U_1$ would not be a vector space (it is not closed under addition).

Comment: As Jerry says, both $U_1$ and $U_2$ are *not* vector subspaces if you mean by them *exactly* the sets of invertible and non-invertible matrices, respectively. So the problem doesn't make sense, as far as I can see. Maybe you mean the subspaces *generated* by linear combinations of invertible and non-invertible matrices, respectively?

Comment: @Jerry Then you need also a product by, let's say, a real number that fulfills the rules of vector space. Which one?

Comment: The problem makes sense : the op doesn't say that $U_1$ has to contain all the invertible matricies.

Comment: @Carot  I think that i need to change the question to "prove or disprove"  and then I got that $U1 \cap U2 = {\{0}\}$ by definition $U1$ contain invertible matrices or ${\{0}\}$ and $U2$ contain only non-invertible  and the sum of two upper triangular matrices is upper triangular  but is this enough to disprove it or is there another way ?

Comment: or How can I find example that disprove this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $U_1=\operatorname{span}(I_3)$ and $U_2$ be the set of all upper triangular $3\times3$ matrices whose bottom rows are zero. Then $V=U_1\oplus U_2$.